# Odata query to fetch count of test cases on tag based from azure analytics service

Tags: azure-devops, odata

I need help in odata query. I am trying to get count of test cases baesed on Tags. I need count based upon 2 different filter.
[https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/{version}//WorkItems](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%7BOrganizationName%7D/%7BProjectName%7D/_odata/%7Bversion%7D//WorkItems)?
$filter=Tags/any(d:d/TagName eq '{tag name}')
&$select=WorkItemId, Title, State

The above example link work with well for one filter. How I can get count of workitems for others tags as well. Like count for Tag 1, count for tag 2

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine these filters with an "**or**" operator when you need to filter on multiple tags.

For example, the following query returns all work items that were tagged with {tag1} or {tag2}:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_odata/{version}/WorkItems?
  $filter=Tags/any(t:t/TagName eq {tag1} or t/TagName eq {tag2})
  &$select=WorkItemId, Title, State
```

More details please refer our official doc here-- [DO use Tags collection property on work items when filtering by tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/odata-query-guidelines?view=azure-devops#-do-use-tags-collection-property-on-work-items-when-filtering-by-tags)